# How to know if a user has used a free trial with Google Play Billing Library?

Tags: android, android-billing

I can't seem to find any relevant information in the Purchase object returned by Google. I know there is a "getFreeTrialPeriod()" method for SkuDetails, but that only returns the duration of the free trial, and not if the user used the free trial or not.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is only possible if you use backend to process subscriptions. Then from your server you can make a [request](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions/get) that will return you JSON with purchase information, where you can find `paymentState` field.

Possible values:

- 0 - Payment pending
- 1 - Payment received
- 2 - Free trial

You can use it if you want to determine if the trial is active now. To determine if a trial was active in the past, your server should receive [Real-time developer notifications](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/getting-ready#configure-rtdn) and store information about purchased subscriptions.

For example, when you receive `SUBSCRIPTION_PURCHASED` notification, you can make the same request as above, to retrieve information about purchase. In the JSON you'll get there will be `priceAmountMicros` field. It should be `0` for trial. So you can store that on your server and check for it later.

Comment: Only if you don't have a backend you can also check the free trial period programmatically starting from the day of the original purchase with `Purchase.getPurchaseTime` and making the calculation by yourself. Obviously to avoid possible mistakes it's best to keep track also of any purchase updates.